# Seagate 2TB external hard drive not detected, after PC crash on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hard-drive, udev, devices

After power crash on my PC, my HDD external could not be detected. But when I try "lusb" and see "syslog" it actually detected.

Please provide me some suggestion.

Screen-captures:

[lusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86423.png)

[syslog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrIsc.png)

Comment: Have you tried re-start (of PC), without HDD attached, and then connect device?

Comment: *"Not detected"*, but *"detected"* ...mmmmh ... Try `more /etc/mtab` to see whether it show up there, if you have not done so already. It may be detected as an usb device but simply not mounted. Also, do you have an `/etc/fstab` entry for any volume on that drive ?